# Getting which application uses a specific port on android

Tags: java, android, port

I have an android native application which hosts a web server inside it.
I want to know which application makes requests before they are processed by my application.
What I have is the port of the calling application.

How can I find out which application is using this port?
I've tried looking for all processes (cat /proc/net/tcp6), but the application with the port I have is not listed (on a rooted device it is).
I also tried playing with lots of options of the netstat command, but I don't get any valuable information.

I need to find a way to find the calling application name on a regular device (not rooted).

Comment: refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70120478/445908

Answer (score 0):

The uid is a field in /proc/net/tcp6, which at least of the moment is readable from an unprivileged app.

Then you can use PackageManager.getNameForUid()

That said, your goal seems like an odd design.